# Syncfusion DataGrid Filter Incorrect Parameter on Click but working on right click

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, datagrid, syncfusion

I currently have a WPF application. WinRT, C#, XAML. 
I have an issue with datagridFilters after creating a new usercontrol from another one(nearly duplicated). I have changed the correspond itemsources and mapping name for columns.

Right now, the user controls opens successfully displaying the items. Sorting can be done. 
I have allowed filtering but i am having a weird issue.

Clicking with the left click on the filter icon does nothing.
Clicking a second time on the filter icon throws a error "Parameter Incorrect"
Exception: "Value does not fall within expected range" in App.g.i.cs

If i click once (which does nothing), and after that i right click, the filter appears correctly.

After the working step above, i can click on the same column filter, with the left click and this will show the filter correctly.

If i want to get other columns filter to appear corrrectly, i have to left click + right click.

What can cause this issue as filters on other usercontrols or window works normally by "left clicking"

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: any possibility of showing us your XAML & code?

Comment: Currently using MVVM pattern and there was an issue with the viewmodels and values in the itemsource not being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

We are unable to analyze further on the reported issue with the given details and so could you please share your XAML and C# code examples along with the application workflow for reproducing the reported issue at our end, thereby we could analyze further and update you with the appropriate solution at the earliest.

Note: I'm working for Syncfusion.